# Js Array defining the count of repeat objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, indexof

I am aware this has been answered before, but I can't make any of them work for this:

I have 10,000+ results & can't change the source .csv file, and has to be plain js.

Question is:

> I am trying to extract the count of each answer, of which there are 3.
> e.g. How many times is '{Q17_Communication: "2"}' displayed in the list of 10,000+?

Format below...

```
0: Object {Q17_Communication: "Has your organization communicated a vision or plan for post-pandemic\nwork?"}
1: Object {Q17_Communication: ""}
2: Object {Q17_Communication: ""}
3: Object {Q17_Communication: "{\"ImportId\":\"QID43\"}"}
4: Object {Q17_Communication: "1"}
5: Object {Q17_Communication: "2"}
6: Object {Q17_Communication: "3"}
7: Object {Q17_Communication: "1"}
8: Object {Q17_Communication: "1"}
9: Object {Q17_Communication: "2"}
10: Object {Q17_Communication: "2"}
11: Object {Q17_Communication: "1"}
12: Object {Q17_Communication: "1"}
13: Object {Q17_Communication: "3"}
14: Object {Q17_Communication: "1"}
15: Object {Q17_Communication: "3"}
16: Object {Q17_Communication: "3"}
17: Object {Q17_Communication: "2"}
18: Object {Q17_Communication: "1"}
...
]
```

Comment: then what's your question? how to parse? the algorithm?

Comment: If this has been answered before, you should link to at least one of those inadequate answers so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: Here's a relevant demo: https://www.crockford.com/pop.html

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```js
const objects = [
  {Q17_Communication: "1"},
  {Q17_Communication: "2"},
  {Q17_Communication: "2"},
  {Q17_Communication: "3"},
  {Q17_Communication: "3"},
  {Q17_Communication: "3"},
];

const counts = {};

objects.forEach((value) => {
  if (!counts[value.Q17_Communication]) {
    counts[value.Q17_Communication] = 0;
  }
  
  counts[value.Q17_Communication]++;
});

console.log(counts);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function count(obj) {  //obj is your array
   let answerCount = [0, 0, 0, 0];
   for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      answerCount[parseInt(obj[i]['Q17_Communication'])]++;
   }
   return answerCount;
}
```

Put your array into the function, and return another array (answerCount) with the number of times each answer appear, just call the function like this

```
let myCount = count(myarray);   //put your array

console.log("Number of '1' : " + myCount[1]);
console.log("Number of '2' : " + myCount[2]);
console.log("Number of '3' : " + myCount[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `array.reduce()` method  you can easily achieve what you want .

See =>

**Array**

```
let array = [{
  Q17_Communication: "Has your organization communicated a vision or plan for post-pandemic\nwork?"
},
  {
    Q17_Communication: ""
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: ""
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "{\"ImportId\":\"QID43\"}"
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "1"
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "2"
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "3"
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "1"
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "1"
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "2"
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "2"
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "1"
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "1"
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "3"
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "1"
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "3"
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "3"
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "2"
  },
  {
    Q17_Communication: "1"
  }];
```

**Using Constant**

```
const count =  array.reduce((total,object)=>{
  // condition 
   object.Q17_Communication === "2" ? total += 1 : null;
   return total;
},0);
console.log(count)
```

**Using Function**

```
function countIt(value){
  const count =  array.reduce((total,object)=>{
    object.Q17_Communication === value ? total += 1 : null;
    return total;
   },0);
   return count;
}


console.log(countIt("2"))
```

> Using array methods is best instead of using conventional for loops..

Comment: @Andy Davies  Does this answer helps you solve problems ? I included a modern method so you can learn more !